# itfoxtec-identity-saml2 , can I set the encryption algorithm while encrypt assertion?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

need to know how to set encryption algorithm like what we do for signing saml response

I had looked at the configuration object, but it seems nothing related to the encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is currently not supported by the libery. You are welcome to add support in a pull request.